# Xpath and html form action post php

Tags: php, html, xpath, validation

I'm trying to create some helper tool for me. Becouse i create a deal agregator and i need to put xpath into my database but fisrt i need to create some tool to help me with validation.

I have a html file where i need to put xpath and then with action i go to generatingxpath.php file where i need to see what i get with xpath that i write.
so...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="generatingxpath.php">

  <p>
    <label for="websource"></label>
    Web source:
    <input name="websource" type="text" id="websource" size="70">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="links"></label>
    Links:  
    <input name="links" type="text" id="links" size="77">
    OK!
  </p>
  <p>

    <label for="title"></label>
    Title:
    <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="78">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="image"></label>
    Image:
    <input name="image" type="text" id="image" size="76">
  show:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="disscount"></label>
    Disscount:
    <input name="disscount" type="text" id="disscount" size="72">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="price"></label>
    Price:
    <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="77">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="description"></label>
    Desription:
    <input name="desription" type="text" id="description" size="72">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="coordinates"></label>
    Coordinates:
    <input name="coordinates" type="text" id="coordinates" size="70">
  lat,lng is:</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Preview">
or    
<input type="submit" name="Add to database" id="Add to database" value="Add To Database">
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my php file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>GENERATING XPATH</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>



<body>

<?php


function curl($url){

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;

}



libxml_use_internal_errors(true);


$websource = $_POST["websource"];
$links = $_POST["links"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$image = $_POST["image"];
$disscount = $_POST["disscount"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$coordinates = $_POST["coordinates"];


//start generating xpath script

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 

@$dom->loadHTMLFile($websource); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$entries = $xpath->query($links);

$output = array(); 

$i = 1;

foreach($entries as $e) {   

  $dom2 = new DOMDocument(); 

  @$dom2->loadHTMLFile($websource . $e->textContent); 

  $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2); 

  $data = array();

  $data['websource']= ($websource . $e->textContent);

  $data['title'] = trim($xpath2->query($title)->item(0)->textContent); 

  $data['description'] = trim($xpath2->query($description)->item(0)->textContent); 

  $data['image'] = trim($xpath2->query($image)->item(0)->textContent); 

  $string = $xpath2->query($coordintes)->item(1)->textContent; 

  preg_match_all('#(([0-9-]+){1,3}.([0-9]+))#is', $string, $matches); 

  $data['lat']=$matches[1];
  $data['lng']=$matches[2];
  $data['disscount'] = trim($xpath2->query($disscount)->item(0)->textContent);
    $data['price'] = trim($xpath2->query($price)->item(0)->textContent);


//print to see that all is fine or need to change some xpath direction

  echo $data['websource'];
  echo $data['links'];
  echo $data['title'];
  echo $data['image'];
  echo $data['disscount'];
  echo $data['price'];
  echo $data['lat'];
  echo $data['lng'];
  echo $data['description'];


    $output[] = $data; 



} 



?>

</body>

</html>
```

I get several errors first in 67 line. for each ... etc.

is there some easy solution to i get result on the same page, so to get text from some website with xpath but to show on html page... ajax??? or something?

What is the best solution for my problem?
How to solve this?

Comment: this stuff will be interesting and will help to many people

Comment: so when I click on Preview I need to got extracted text from some URL that i type into textfiled with based on xpath

Comment: very sorry for my english, is very bad, but I working to change that soon

Comment: see th dem test.pluspon.com/xpathadd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html and php desription/description don't match. Try changing

```
<label for="description"></label>
Desription:
<input name="desription" type="text" id="description" size="72">
```

into this:

```
<label for="description"></label>
Desription:
<input name="description" type="text" id="description" size="72">
```

You could use jQuery $.ajax to load the text from generatingxpath.php without reloading the page.
Include jQuery, you can get it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and use `<script src="your/folder/jquery.js"></script>`
and to load the text:

```
$.post("generatingxpath.php", {var:$('#input').val()}, function(data) {
     $("#result").html(data);
});
```

If you want to use jQuery I'd recommend reading the Tutorials/Documentation at jQuery.com

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/VqPHJ/

Comment: but how to do that. please shoe me at some online code editor!

Comment: not working Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pluspon/public_html/test/generatingxpath.php on line 67

Comment: I copied the code and tested it offline, it works for me. Have you changed anything in generatingxpath.php? Also, I don't get your php error but a js error: SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8203' on 27.

Comment: I'm still getting the javascript error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on line 27. But no php errors.

Comment: test.php http://ideone.com/mEKeS and the generatingxpath.php http://ideone.com/1VKNf